# I want to return file name in Python. How can I properly do it?

Tags: python, discord.py, programming-languages

So I want to generate a text document in Python, but I seem to be having a problem, when I want it to return the file name, I get this error:

```
File "D:\My Applications\ghBot (Python)\text_file_generator.py", line 5, in writeToAndUploadFile
    return textfile.name()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

text_file_generator.py

```
   def writeToAndUploadFile(filename, filecontents):
        textfile = open("text_documents/" + filename + ".txt", "w")
        textfile.write(filecontents)
        textfile.close()
        return textfile.name()
```

main.py

```
  @client.command(aliases = ["newtextdoc"])
        async def new_text_doc(ctx, filename, *, filecontents):
        await ctx.send("Text document successfully generated.")
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(text_file_generator.writeToandUploadFile(filename, filecontents)))
```

If this is obvious, sorry. I'm slightly new at making applications in Python.

Comment: `textfile.name` is an attribute. You don't have to call it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call common attribute, it is not a function. Try `return textfile.name`

Answer (score 2):

If you only need file name without extension
Then,
In writeToAndUploadFile()

```
   return filename
```

& if with extension then

```
   return filename+'.txt'
```

It should be worked

There is no function attribute with  .name() attributes

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Testfile_name = filename + ".txt"
return Testfile_name
```